# Unable to click intercepted element in wdio 7

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio

I'm using wdio 7 last couple of weeks. but still unable to resolve intercepted element.

In protractor, I'm using

```
            browser.actions().
            click($(".pay-modal-container i[class='webfont-date_range']")).
            sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).
            sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).
            sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).
            perform();
```

Don't know In Wdio how it works. Please help me if anyone has an idea of it.

Note : Already used `browser.execute("arguments[0].click()", locator);` not doing anything if i used into script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.performActions([{
"type": "pointer",
"id": "click on add button",
parameters: { pointerType: 'mouse' },
actions: [
{ type: 'pointerMove', x: 1, y: 1, origin: browser.findElement("css selector", locator) },
{ type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
{ type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 },
]
}
]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `ElementClickInterceptedException` occurs when a pop-up gets in the way of a regular Selenium/WebDriver click, (eg: [How do I close pop-up windows with Selenium in Python when I don't know when they will pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678496/how-do-i-close-pop-up-windows-with-selenium-in-python-when-i-dont-know-when-the/70684209#70684209))

When that happens, you have two options:

1. First click to close the pop-up that's in the way.
2. Use a Javascript click instead of a regular click.

Given that WDIO is already a Javascript framework, you should have no troubles running a Javascript command to perform that click. Or you may decide to click to close the pop-up first.

Comment: Right, but there are no pop-ups or anything else.  It's working fine when I'm using a protractor.